# Set default scheme in Redshift

Tags: schema, redshift

I'm trying to set the default schema to a user in Redshift with `alter` option, because I do not want it to write to the public schema by default. I am using the following order:

```sql
alter user user_1234 set search_path to atc_schema;
```

It does not give me any error, but when I create a table with the user without specifying the schema, it is not created in the schema indicated in the previous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from using `Aginity`, since this client applies that the default path is `$user, public`.

I've tried it in `SQL Workbench/J` and it works without problems.